# Xtrareport da una excepción System.OutOfMemory en VISUAL STUDIO y DEVExpress version17.13

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2017, devexpress

hola quiera saber si son tan amable y me pueden ayudar el problema al cargar el reporte DevExpress me manda este error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
donde  quiero cargar 3996 registros en el detalle la verdad no se por que me manda ese error revise el procedure en sql y me lo hace bien el problema es en el reporte de devexpress.

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[Imprimir_Marbete_TODOS]

as
    SELECT
'MARBETE No.'+' '+  CONVERT(NVARCHAR(11),a.MARBETE) MARBETE,
b.COD_BODEGA,
b.BODEGA,
a.COD_ART CODIGO,
a.DES_ART DESCRIPCION,
tu.DES_UNI 'UNIDAD DE MEDIDA',
a.LOCALIZA UBICACION,
'INVENTARIO FISICO AL'+' '+convert(nvarchar(11),c.FECHAF_INV,103) FECHA
        FROM
    ARTFISIC AS a
    left JOIN  T_UNI AS tu ON tu.COD_UNI = a.COD_UNI
    INNER JOIN BODEGA AS b ON b.COD_BODEGA = a.COD_BODEGA AND b.CODLOCA = a.CODLOCA
    INNER  JOIN CONTROL AS c ON c.NIVEL_AREA = a.CODLOCA
    
ORDER BY a.MARBETE asc
```

gracias por su ayuda

Dios los bendiga